# Convergence of the sequence $a_n=\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}$ when $(x_n)_n$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> (i) Assuming that $(x_n)_n$ converges, investigate whether $(a_n)_n$ converges.
>
> (ii)Assuming that $(a_n)_n$ converges, investigate whether $(x_n)_n$ converges.

For (ii):

If we choose $x_n=(-1)^n$, then $(a_n)_n$ converges as $(x_n)_n$ doesn't converge. And if we choose $x_n=1$, then $(a_n)_n$ converges as $(x_n)_n$ converges. So for part (ii), $(x_n)_n$ can both converge or not converge assuming that $(a_n)_n$ converges.

For (i):

I believe $(a_n)_n$ should be always converging, but I couldn't prove it, any help?

Thanks for your effort and time in advance.

Edit: I think the following question says that $(x_n)_n$ always converges when $(a_n)_n$ converges. Is my reasoning in part (ii) wrong?
[Prove $x_n$ converges if $x_n$ is a real sequence and $s_n=\frac{x_0+x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n+1}$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733362/prove-x-n-converges-if-x-n-is-a-real-sequence-and-s-n-fracx-0x-1-cdots?rq=1)

Comment: The first part is answered (for example) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155839/on-cesàro-convergence-if-x-n-to-x-then-z-n-fracx-1-dots-x-nn

Comment: That link answers the first part but can you check my edit before closing as duplicate

Comment: Your examples for (ii) are fine. Note that the question that you are now referring to proves the reverse implication *under additional conditions.*